# exception_catching is disabled - This exception cannot be caught

Tags: javascript, opencv, exception, opencv-solvepnp

I am using the mjyc/opencv.js version and when i run the cv.solvePnP fucntion, I get this

```
/home/madhan/solvingpnp/node_modules/@mjyc/opencv.js/opencv.js:85
              throw ex
              ^
6410192 - Exception catching is disabled, this exception cannot be caught. Compile with -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 or DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=2 to catch.
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
```

when i run `node --trace-uncaught pnp.js`, i am getting this.

```
/home/madhan/solvingpnp/node_modules/@mjyc/opencv.js/opencv.js:85
              throw ex
              ^
6410192 - Exception catching is disabled, this exception cannot be caught. Compile with -s DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=0 or DISABLE_EXCEPTION_CATCHING=2 to catch.
Thrown at:
    at /home/madhan/solvingpnp/node_modules/@mjyc/opencv.js/opencv.js:85:15
    at emit (events.js:310:20)
    at internal/process/execution.js:164:25
```

this is the chunk of code i am getting the error at

```
var success = cv.solvePnP(obj_pts, img_pts, cam_mat, dist_coeff,rvec,tvec,true);
console.log(success);
```

Does anybody understand what is happening here?